# How to connect to postgresql in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, mikro-orm

I have a postgresql db running in a docker container on my machine. I started it with this run command.

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -d \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$PG_PASS \
-e POSTGRES_USER=$PG_USER \
-e POSTGRES_DB=$PG_NAME \
-v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
--name $PG_CONTAINER_NAME \
postgres:alpine
```

I have confirmed that this created the db using the environment variables by also running a pgadmin4 container and connecting to this container using its container name.

Now I am trying to connect my express app to the db. I am using a orm called mikroorm. The ts code is

```
const orm = await MikroORM.init({
    dbName: 'ketopal',
    user: 'ketopaladmin',
    password: 'ketopaladmin',
    type: 'postgresql',
    debug: !__prod__,
    entities: [Post],
    host: '172.17.0.2',
    port: 5432
})
```

This produces a one line error,

> MikroORM failed to connect to database ketopal on postgresql://ketopaladmin:*****@172.17.0.2:5432

But I don't know why or how to fix it. 172.17.0.2 is the IP docker gave to the container.

In my perfect world, you all could tell me how to get docker to make localhost:5432 point to the docker container, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your express app works on same machine without using docker? Did you tried write 'localhost' instead of '172.17.0.2'? It should work with 'localhost' param, because you have forwarded 5432 port from container to 5432 port on your host machine

Comment: Since `localhost` means the host machine, not the container, I recommend using `container_name` instead of IP Address in your `host` part.

Comment: I'll add an edit to the post to clarify, I have tried not specifying host, using localhost and container_name, and the ip of the bridge and the ip of the docker container. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score -1):

Thought I'd document here incase someone also runs into this. I had a local postgres process running on port 5432, so when I attempted to "publish" the container to that same port, it failed to do so, even though it created the container and was otherwise working. I adjusted the run command to map port 54321 to 5432.

```
docker run -p 54321:5432 -d \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$PG_PASS \
-e POSTGRES_USER=$PG_USER \
-e POSTGRES_DB=$PG_NAME \
-v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
--name $PG_CONTAINER_NAME \
postgres:alpine
```

TLDR; If you have something running that already claimed a port, running a container on that port won't work.